# Electron app not launching at windows startup

Tags: electron, registry

I am using electron [app.setLoginItemSettings(settings)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows) to enable my application to autostart at login. This is how I am implementing it:

```
const executable_path = process.execPath;
const exeName = path.basename(process.execPath);

...

const createWindow = () => {
...

ipcMain.on('close-me', (evt, arg) => {
        var boot = settings.get("startatboot");
        if (boot) {
            app.setLoginItemSettings({
                openAtLogin: true,
                path: executable_path,
                name: exeName,
                args: [
                    '--processStart', `"${exeName}"`,
                    '--process-start-args'
                ]
            })
        } else {
            app.setLoginItemSettings({
                openAtLogin: false,
                openAsHidden: false
            });
        }
        app.quit()
    });
...
};
```

And this result in the following inside the register (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)

`Test Autorun.exe` for `name`

`C:\Program Files\Test Autorun\Test Autorun.exe --processStart "Test Autorun.exe" --process-start-args` for `data`

Now inside my `package.json` file I defined the following:

```
{
    "name": "apptest",
    "productName": "Test Autorun",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Test Autorun",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "publish": "electron-forge publish",
        "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
        "build-installer": "electron-builder"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "apptest",
...
```

Now my problem is that the application is not running on start and I have no idea why this is happening, I tried changing a lot of the values to end up with this register content. All the attempts before were showing as different programs inside `windows startup settings`.

I have got to fill what I think is correct data inside the registers but there is something I am missing but I have no idea what it is. Any help would go a long way, thanks.

EDIT:

When I launch the app normally it always asks the user to allow the app with `unknown publisher` to make changes to the device. I don't know if that is why the app is not running on start or if the app would run showing the same message awaiting user approval.

EDIT2:

it is adding the register inside the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and not the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, it was related to the `unknown publisher` popup; so, when I edited the registry entry related to `UAC` by using the following command line code shown below, the application started on boot.

```
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/83678).